# В чем ошибка, что не переопределяется в методах Swift

Tags: swift, функции, переменные, методы, переопределение

Не судите строго я новичок в языке программирование swift, помогите решите проблему, что я не так написал в коде, просто я больше в ruby программировал.

```
class Z {

func zt(x:String){
print(x)

 }  
}
class X:Z{

}    

override func zt(x:String)   { 
super.zt(x:String) 
 print("zoom\(x)")  
 }       
}
var x=X()
x.zt(x:"35")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переопределение функции суперкласса осуществляется внутри подкласса:

```
class X:Z {

    override func zt(x:String)   {

        super.zt(x:x)
        print("zoom\(x)")
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо вам за доброту!!! что мне ответили